# Connect from application to SQL Server (ONLY Theoretical!)

Tags: sql-server

I don't know how to connect from a self-written application to a SQL Server. I have added an application role to the SQL Server already. Do I need a SQL Server login or only a database user? I know that after I'm connected I can run the procedure `sp_setapprole` to access the database as an application. How does this work in theory?

Comment: It's two layers: **first**; you need a **login** to the server, so you can even connect to it; this decides whether it's a SQL Server login (with username + password), or a Windows login (based on a Windows user or group). Once you have a login, you need to have a **user** in each database that this login should be allowed to connect to and use; the user is linked to the login

Comment: Give a try: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et2khGnrIqc

Answer (score 0):

You need a connection string 
(instructions on how to connect to the SQL Server: URL,PORT,USERNAME,PASSWORD) and a command to be Executed.

I'm sure there are a lot of instructions online for you, just give it a quick google search:

%Programming_Language & "SQL Connection String"